# Are there logic analyzers for large signals (5+ volts)?

Tags: logic-analyzer

I've used logic analyzers for <5V signals but I'm curious if there are analyzers for larger voltages.

Since logic analyzers don't display analog levels, could you use a logic analyzer to check for digital changes that occur at 12V?

Comment: You mean like an oscilloscope with a digital analyzer option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ordinary professional logic analyzer such as the [Tek TLA600](http://www.testequity.com/documents/pdf/tla600.pdf) can be used for 12V if you set the threshold to 6V.

[image]

Comment: Another data point: The HP 166x series have a +/-40V max input range with a threshold range of +/-6V.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the data sheet or  user manual of the LA which you are using, to find the absolute maximum ratings section. There you will see what is the maximum input voltage for a channel. In no case, you should apply a voltage greater than this.

Logic Analysers are meant to give a digital visual representation of the signals you are interested in. And, digital can be thought of as a special case of analog, where we talk only about high and low. In LA, we can set the threshold levels for determining if the signal has gone *high* or *low*. This allows you some limited amount of flexibility, but never expect to see a continuously variable signal, as we can do with a DSO.